# Validate data binding in XAML in compile time

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I’m working on WPF based application. Environment is VS2008 SP1 with .NET 3.5 SP 1. 
In our development we are using MVVM pattern widely.

I.e. application developers write Models and ViewModels (C#), then UI developers will write Views using WPF Binding (XAML). Application developers also write unit tests on top of ViewModels.
We are using Continuous Integration methodology and we are diond build and executing unit test on each modification

The problem is a lack of process or tools of data binding correctness validation in XAML. 
For example:

1. App developer writes property **NmberOfApples** and unit tests to check its correct behavior
2. UI developer creates user control and bind it to the property
3. App  developer finds that property has misspelling and fix its name to **NumberOfApples**
4. It would be compilation time errors in any C# code uses **NmberOfApples** property, and such errors will be easy to catch (Continuous Integration)
5. Data binding in XAML files are not going to be validated and it will be run time error

My question will be “Is there any tool or methodology that help us validate data binding correctness in XAML in compile time?”

Comment: I have found out, that I have posted a duplicate of your question. :(    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208011/detect-in-xaml-broken-bindings-already-at-compile-time   
But I have become a good solution on it! I would not post a solution here, due it's not from me and otherwise it would be a plagiarism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution to your problem is discussed in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/T4Metadata.aspx#_Toc239401270).

The basic idea is to create a ViewModel MetaData set of static(c#) classes that hold the string value of the properties of your ViewModel classes which you can then use in your xaml. The article explains how to use T4 text generation to create these static metadata classes. You could use any code generation tool of your preference.

so your VM has the following:

```
namespace Mine
{
  public class MyViewModel
  {
    public int MyInt {get;set;}
   public string MyString {get;set;}  
  }
}
```

And you code generation would create this:

```
namespace Mine.MetaData
{
  public static class MyViewModelMetaData
  {
    public const string MyInt = "MyInt";
    public const string MyString = "MyString";
  }
}
```

and then in your xaml you would add the namespace to your xaml and bind your controls to the metadata class

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path={x:Static Metadata:MyViewModelMetadata.MyInt}}"/>
```

If you use an add-in like [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) then it will give you intellisense on the properties of the static class and also because you are referencing an exact property in a static class, when the static class gets regenerated your xaml should not compile.

It's pretty slick, I think it's awesome and it has the chance of keeping most people sane, but your mileage may vary. :)

EDIT:

By the way, I don't buy the "ViewModels are tightly coupled to the Views". In my opinion Views are inextricably bound to their ViewModels, but it should only be one way. ViewModels should be completely independent of any view implementation. It's like the ViewModel is the interface and the View is the concrete implemented class. So for this reason I don't put in any WPF-specific properties(e.g. Visibility enumeration) into my ViewModel because that binds me to use WPF for eternity(which isn't really a bad thing :) ), but it compromises maintenance.

Comment: It is great approach, thank you for pointing it. I'm going to keep this question unanswered for a couple more days, just in case if somebody would like to share other tricks.

Comment: @Jose If you do not keep properties like "visibility" in the view model, how do you change the visibility of the UI component since you cannot embed conditional logic inside XAML?

Answer (score 2):

If you install [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), one of the (many) features you will get is "code inspection". One of the things this inspection will detect is cases where your binding does not resolve to a property on your data context. You can easily filter the "Inspection Results" window to only show these issues.

Note that you must explicitly state the type of your view model in your XAML resources for this to work.

[image: Example of ReSharper inspections]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of arguably good scenarios where this behavior is actually desired.  In any case, it is by design that bindings swallow errors and is the reason you are going to have trouble finding anything that will help you with this.

The best thing I've seen is an exception validation handler that will display binding errors:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.exceptionvalidationrule.aspx

The argument for this is views and ViewModels are meant to be decoupled to the point where a View could be used for multiple ViewModels.  It also aids in the "Bendability" of the views so that theoretically designer types can style a view without running into a bunch of errors while they are doing it.  I realize this might not fit with your process, but that's the story.

Comment: I know that it is cool to have View and ViewModel decoupled. Question here, how I can validate their "compatibility".

Comment: Yeah... I know that was your question.  That was the "arguably".  Unfortunately I think you are going to have to focus on that ExceptionValidationRule possibly and automated UI tests.  I know that's a bit crappy.

Answer (score 1):

It's been years since the original question was asked and answered but as I just checked, the solution might have gotten simpler since then. ReSharper seems to offer correct Intellisense without the need to generate the static classes mentioned in the accepted answer.

But I haven't witnessed the compile-time error as stated in the accepted answer. I even tried using [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] to no avail. Please stand me corrected if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we are using [Caliburn](http://www.codeplex.com/caliburn) and unit tests in the way explained in this article [Testing Bindings In WPF](http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2009/02/19/testing-bindings-in-wpf.aspx). The drawback of this solution, UI developer writes code that has only meaning to validate bindings and can be omitted if MS (or somebody) would write XAML validation compiler.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the previous answer. This is "by design" and there is no way to check it at compile time.

I've also found it a pain.

The best and only way I found is to check the Visual Studio debug output at runtime. Any binding error will be printed as soon as you open the window containing it.

I agree if you think it's a crappy and unreliable method, but it should work if you don't have a huge number of windows. You could create a semi-formal test practice where once in a while you open any window looking specifically for binding errors.

Comment: Are you suggesting manually walking over all application windows?