# Detect broken bindings in XAML already at compile time

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

It is a simple and frequent, I think,  scenario - you bind in XAML a dependency property to property in the viewmodel and later rename the property in viewmodel and forget to rename it in XAML. So is the binding broken.

Is there a way to detect such a broken bindings already at compile time?

Comment: For UWA Microsoft introduced x:Bind and it is compilable bindings unfortunately for WPF binding still base on reflections. I will take a look if there is a way to use x:Bind in WPF/

Comment: if view DataContext is set at design time, designer shows underline for inccorrect binding paths. so design-time DataContext is a kind of insurance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could add the VM-class to your Binding line this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(viewModels:MyViewModel.MyItemsSource)}" />
```

with:

```
namespace ViewModels{
    public class MyViewModel{
        public ICollectionView MyItemsSource {get; set;}
    }
}
```

This shows you BindingErrors at DesignTime

Comment: Amazing, there are an error at compile time, if I use it, but the binding does not work at run time. I get System.ArgumentNullException; "Key cannot be null". I bind Text TextBox to a string Property in VM.

Comment: @Rekshino: I think this error is generated at `DesignTime` (when this is builded). The normal compiler doesn't generate this error (as I see in build -> output [errors: 0]). I don't know how to tell your compiler to generate this error. But with this you have a chance to see where your Bindings will fail. I think the `RuntimeException` results is caused by `TwoWay` BindingMode.

Comment: No, at compile time is all OK, it works as it should(no error, if property's name is correct and error otherwise)! , but there are an error at run time, if I compile it with no errors. The same is with OneWay binding. Only OneWayToSource gets no error, but this mode is seldom.

Comment: @Rekshino: Did you initialise your bounded property with some text? Like: `public string MyText{get{return _myText;}set{_myText = value; OnPropertyChanged();}}` and `private string _myText = "";`

Comment: Yes, it is initialized. And binding works fine without (namespace:VMClassName.).

Comment: @Rekshino: Can you update your question with some sourcecode (simplified)? So we are able to see how your VM is bound and stuff. I can't reproduce the problem (I use Caliburn for MVVM).

Comment: I have found out, why your code has not worked for me. 'Path=' was omitted. Can you edit your code to {Binding Path=(viewModels.MyViewModel.MyItemsSource)}