# Accessing control from datatemplate inside of gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListView` that displays a table with various columns. Each cell of a row in the table contains a different type of control; I am trying to allow the user to edit the data in each row by selecting a row and double-clicking it to make the cells editable. So I have been able to get all of them to work with the exception of the column that contains `ComboBox`es.

**XAML code:**

This is the XAML code for the `ListView`. It has about 7 columns but I am focusing on the column with `ComboBox`es as depicted here.

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0" Height="315" Width="560" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
     <ListView.View>
        <GridView>

            <!-- More Grid column code here -->

            <GridViewColumn Header="Fleet" Width="70">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="locationCmboBx" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SchoolLocations, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="OnCmboBxLoad" IsEnabled="False" Width="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>   

        <!-- More Grid column code here --> 

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**C# code:**

So here in the code-behind I am trying to use the `VisualTreeHelper` as recommended by others to get access to the `locationsCmboBx` (*ComboBox*) nested inside of the `DataTemplate`, `CellTemplate` and other *XAML* headers in the `ListView`.

```
// More code before here
ListView listViewItem = (ListView)(MyListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyListView));
ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(listViewItem);

DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)myDataTemplate.FindName("locationsCmboBx", myContentPresenter);

// More code before here
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem)
        {
            return (childItem)child;
        }                    
        else
        {
            childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
            {
                return childOfChild;
            }                        
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So everything I have works but when I debug through the code and get to the `FindName` function `ComboBox` is `null`. Ultimately, I want to set the `IsEnabled` property on it and get the `SelectedValue` from the `locationsCmboBx`. I believe I am missing something but not sure of what. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is a typo by combo box's name in XAML `locationCmboBx` and in code behind is `location`**s**`CmboBx`.
The code:

```
ListView listViewItem = (ListView)(MyListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyListView));
```

is also wrong. Argument of `ContainerFromItem()` must be a data item. Returned type is also wrong. It must be `ListViewItem`

I would recommend you to use a ViewModel + bindings and not a code behind to access the data. So you can avoid such a tipo errors. See also: [Detect in XAML broken bindings already at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208011/detect-in-xaml-broken-bindings-already-at-compile-time)

Comment: So I fixed the typo but it still does not work. Could you provide an example for the ViewModel + bindings method to access the data? (Or was that supposed to be what was in the link?)

Comment: [Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301678/%2fArticles%2f301678%2fStep-by-Step-WPF-Data-Binding-with-Comboboxes)

Comment: @DevMent I have edited an answer. And it works on my side, I get the `ComboBox`.

Comment: I looked at the explanation in the "Example" link  you provided and I understand most of that already but how does that help to access the combobox that is in the datatemplate?

Comment: How about this line: 'ListViewItem listViewItem = (ListViewItem)(GuardbandListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyListView.Items));' I have the "ContainerFromItem" method looking into the list of MyListView items.

Comment: You don't have to acces combobox, you have to create properties in ViewModel, which will be bound with combobox, it's IsEnabled etc. dependent properties.

Comment: So if I also wanted to get the selected item from the combobox I could do it by creating a property for it in the ViewModel class that I setup?

Comment: Yes you can do it such way.

Comment: So I have a different problem that maybe related. Should I create a new post for it or just edit this one?

Comment: I just made a new post

Answer (score 0):

I found this information:

```
public static class ListViewHelper 
    { 
        public static FrameworkElement GetElementFromCellTemplate(ListView listView, Int32 column, Int32 row, String name) 
        { 
            if (row >= listView.Items.Count || row < 0) 
            { 
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException('row'); 
            } 
            GridView gridView = listView.View as GridView; 

            if (gridView == null) { return null; } 
            
            if (column >= gridView.Columns.Count || column < 0) 
            { 
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException('column'); 
            } 
            
            ListViewItem item = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listView.Items[row]) as ListViewItem; 
            
            if (item != null) 
            { 
                GridViewRowPresenter rowPresenter = GetFrameworkElementByName(item); 
                
                if (rowPresenter != null) 
                { 
                    ContentPresenter templatedParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rowPresenter, column) as ContentPresenter; 
                    DataTemplate dataTemplate = gridView.Columns[column].CellTemplate; 
                    if (dataTemplate != null && templatedParent != null) 
                    { 
                        return dataTemplate.FindName(name, templatedParent) as FrameworkElement; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            return null; 
        } 
        private static T GetFrameworkElementByName(FrameworkElement referenceElement) where T : FrameworkElement 
        { 
            FrameworkElement child = null; 
            
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(referenceElement); i++) 
            { 
                child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(referenceElement, i) as FrameworkElement; 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(child); 
                if (child != null && child.GetType() == typeof(T)) 
                { 
                    break; 
                } 
                else if (child != null) 
                { 
                    child = GetFrameworkElementByName(child); 
                    if (child != null && child.GetType() == typeof(T)) 
                    { 
                        break; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            return child as T; 
        } 
    }
```

Source: [How do I access the ui element at a row/cell in my GridView?](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/wpf/listview/how-do-i-access-the-ui-element-at-a-row-cell-in-my-gridview)